# How to select adjacent vertices in a 2d matrix using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional matrix of order m *n

```
00 01 02 03 ....0n
10 11 12 13 ....1n
20 21 22 23 ....2n
..
m0 m1 m2  m3 ...mn
```

If I give input as 11 then the adjacent points should be selected. There is one more attribute called radius. If radius is given as 1 then points:

```
(00,01,02,10,12,20,21,22)
```

will get selected and stored in an array. If radius is given 2 then for point 22:

```
(00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 23, 24, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 40, 11, 42, 43, 44)
```

should get selected.

Help me how to do this. Thank you :)

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't work like "Thats my problem but I'm too lazy, pls do it for me". Provide your attempts and you will get helped, were not doing your work for you. Thank you :)

Comment: @TomDoodler actually I did for the first layer. But I'm not getting how to do for the second layer. And I'm asking for any logic not the complete program. Plz dont misunderstand me.. :)

Comment: Maybe this may help? I guess you just need to filter your array in some way, unless im having a complete brain fart and this is of no help at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/3jw22dm2/

Comment: The logic behind it would be: for `MN` et radius `r` you are looking for all `ab` elements that verify: `|a-M| <= 2 && |b-N| <= 2`

Answer (score 0):

Basically find the wanted interval of the directions and apply them in a loop for the items of the array.

```js
var width = 10,
    height = 5,
    array = Array.apply(Array, { length: height }).map(function (a, i) {
        return Array.apply(Array, { length: width }).map(function (b, j) {
            return 'y' + i + 'x' + j;
        });
    }),
    aa = getAdjacent(array, 2, 3, 2);

function getAdjacent(a, x, y, r) {
    var minX = Math.max(x - r, 0),
        maxX = Math.min(x + r, a[0].length - 1),
        minY = Math.max(y - r, 0),
        maxY = Math.min(y + r, a.length - 1),
        xx, yy,
        result = [];

    for (yy = minY; yy <= maxY; yy++) {
        for (xx = minX; xx <= maxX; xx++) {
            if (x !== xx || y !== yy) {
                result.push(a[yy][xx]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log('array', array);
console.log('result', aa);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```